# How to make any area visible and hidden by Knockoutjs based on checkbox chekced

Tags: html, knockout.js

i like to use Knockoutjs in page where a particular `<ul>` portion will be visible if a specific check box is checked. if check the `<ul>` portion will be visible and if unchecked then `<ul>` portion will be invisible. i searched google and found people do this way which is not same to my requirement.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

they are using this trick `data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0"`
they are checking if view model has more task then it will be visible or not but in my case i need to use checkbox. anyone can tell me how to achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need another observable binded to the checkbox, in javascript:

```
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.isListVisible = ko.observable(true);
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);    
};
```

and in html:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isListVisible" > Show list

<p>Your items:</p>
<ul width="50" data-bind="foreach: items, visible: isListVisible"> 
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxLdxqhg/)

Comment: i am just reading many knockout js related article for getting hold on it. can u tell me that can we do all kind of dom manipulation with ko without using jquery?  what is the performance of ko? is it good compared with angular or backbonejs ? share your experience. thanks

Comment: @Mou Think of it this way: Knockout is primarily used to control UI representation, whereas Angular is a JavaScript framework that is much better suited for large, complex enterprise applications. It provides not only UI binding, but also best practices for application structure, development and testing.

Comment: thanks for reply but u missed my 2 question that 1) ko can we do all kind of dom manipulation like jquery. if yes then i could stop using JQ rather use KO. 2) what is the performance of ko? 3) full SPA apps can be developed by KO?

Comment: 1. KO is not about DOM manipulation, it's about binding. So you can use it with JQuery or with vanila Javascript. 2) Latest KO version is pretty fast , but of course all depends on the task 3) Yes, for example http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Comment: thanks for answer. i heard that routing need to be supported if someone need to develop SPA apps with any js library but heard ko does not have routing support. so what is your suggestion?